# how to compare resultset two objects

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

Plase help,How to checked check box based on resultset object comparison? i have two tables in db.
one is subjects, it contains

```
  category         | sub_category
    --------------+-------------
Arts and Humanities|   Arts and Humanities (General)
Arts and Humanities|   History
Arts and Humanities|   Language and Linguistics
Arts and Humanities|   Media Technology
```

and another is topic_alerts, it contains

```
     username              |   topic  
     ----------------------------------------
hareesh.nare@gmail.com |  History
    hareesh.nare@gmail.com |  Language and Linguistics
   hareesh.nare@gmail.com  |Media Technology
```

in my jsp page 
Displaying **sub_category** based on selected **category**

after that

```
 <% 
         String topic="";
             Connection con=Singleton.getMySqlConnection();
              Statement st=con.createStatement();
            Statement st1=con.createStatement();
            String userid=(String)session.getAttribute("userid");
          ResultSet rs1=st.executeQuery("select sub_category from subjects where category='"+category+"'");     
          ResultSet rs2=st1.executeQuery("select topic from topic_alerts where username='"+userid+"' order by topic ");
        %>
```

now i want to checked a checkbox based on **topic_alerts** table **topic** values are equals to **subjects** table **sub_category** values like..

```
<%while(rs1.next()){%>

<%if(rs2.next()){%>
<%
topic=rs2.getString(1);
System.out.println("topic="+topic);
System.out.println("alert="+rs1.getString(1));

%>
<%}%>
      <tr class="tablePlainWhite" style='vertical-align:top'>
<td><input type="checkbox" value="<%=rs1.getString(1)%>" <%if((rs1.getString(1).equals(topic))){%> CHECKED name="top"<%}else{%> name="topic" <%}%>></td>
<td><%=rs1.getString(1)%></td>
<td nowrap align="center"><a href="">Latest Results</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="">Archive/Details</a></td>
<td align="center">Weekly</td></tr>
 <%}%>
```

here only last checkbox **Media Technology** is checked before **History** and **Language and Linguistics** is not checked.

how to fix these..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

but i'm using like

```
<%if(rs2.next()){%>
<%
topic=rs2.getString(1);
%>
<%}%>   

      <tr class="tablePlainWhite" style='vertical-align:top'>
<td><input type="checkbox" value="<%=rs1.getString(1)%>" <%if((rs1.getString(1).equals(topic))){%> CHECKED name="top" <%}else{%> name="topic" <%rs2.previous();%> <%}%>></td>
<td><%=rs1.getString(1)%></td>
</tr>
 <%}%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic of comparing two resultSet:

```
while(rs1.next()){
// Compare till rs1 reach to the last record
  while(rs2.next()){
     if(){
       // Coding
     }
  }
//will move resultSet cursor to first position.
rs2.first();
}
```